# Bind a class-level boolean to WPF "IsChecked" property

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, data-binding

I have a VB.NET WPF application that operates in two different modes (design mode and evaluate mode, respectively). I have added a menu option and toggle button so that the user may choose which mode s/he is using with ease. Of course, the whole application acts differently depending on whether it is in design mode or not as well, so it makes sense to create a class-level boolean to represent working in design mode, and bind these items `IsChecked` property to it.

At first, I tried to add the binding in the code-behind, like this:

```
Class MainWindow
    Private IsInDesignMode As Boolean = True

    Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender as Object, e as RoutedEventArgs)
        SetUpDataBindings()
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetUpDataBindings()
        tglDesignMode.IsChecked = New Binding(IsInDesignMode)
        mnuDesignMode.IsChecked = New Binding(IsInDesignMode)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then I read that controls can only be bound to properties, and all of the examples I read showed public properties, so I changed line 2 above to read:

```
Public Property IsInDesignMode as Boolean = True
```

But in both of these cases the button and menu were not checked on startup, and did not remain checked/unchecked together. So I tried a different strategy, using the XAML:

```
                <ToggleButton Name="tbnDesignMode"
                              IsChecked="{Binding IsInDesignMode}">
                    DESIGN MODE
                </ToggleButton>
```

That didn't work either. I did more research, and found some people using `ElementName` and `Path` in their XAML. So I tried the following:

```
                <MenuItem Name="mnuDesignMode"
                          Header="_Design Mode"
                          IsCheckable="True"
                          IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=mnuDesignMode, Path=IsInDesignMode}"/>
```

That didn't work either. I also saw some people using custom converters, but they didn't explain much about what the converter was doing (the conversion from C# to VB didn't help there, either).

Long story short, can someone please help me set up a binding from the `IsChecked` properties of these controls to a class-level boolean, and explain the why and how along the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the below code.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<StackPanel>
    <ToggleButton Name="tbnDesignMode"
                          IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsInDesignMode,
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                     AncestorType=Window}}">
        DESIGN MODE
    </ToggleButton>
    <MenuItem Name="mnuDesignMode"
                      Header="_Design Mode"
                      IsCheckable="True"
                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsInDesignMode,
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                     AncestorType=Window}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Class MainWindow
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Private isInDesignModeValue As Boolean
    Public Property IsInDesignMode() As Boolean
        Get
            Return isInDesignModeValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            isInDesignModeValue = value
            OnPropertyChanged1("IsInDesignMode")
        End Set
    End Property


    Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        IsInDesignMode = True
    End Sub


    Public Event PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged



    Protected Sub OnPropertyChanged1(ByVal name As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(name))
    End Sub

End Class
```

But i would suggest you to look for MVVM approach rather than code behind.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I looked up more on implementing MVVM, too, and found out more of the methods behind that. In that context, data binding these properties makes a lot more sense.

Comment: I started going through your code more, so I could be able to reimplement it someplace else, and I have 2 more questions. 1 - What is the syntax for `RelativeSource` in the XAML? 2 - I assume the code to raise a new event is so that the window can update its contents when the property changes; is that correct, even though the window has no code in XAML or VB that does that?

Comment: I suggest you to go through Data Binding in WPF which will answer all your questions. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612(v=vs.110).aspx.